# CodeIgniter captcha image not working when online

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I'll try to be as specific as possible. I used codeigniter captcha helper to generate a captcha for user verification on my website, it is working great on ly localhost but when i uploaded the website online, the captcha was not showing anything, apparently, when i viewed it using developer tools the img tag containing the captcha image was not there at all.

The code is:

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$vals = array(
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
        'font_path' => './fonts/VeraSe.ttf',
        );

$img = create_captcha($vals);
$x = $this->session->set_userdata('captcha', $img['word']); 

$data['image'] = $img['image'];
$data['captcha1'] = $img['word'];
$this->load->view('signup', $data);
```

and in the view:

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

Comment: Check the folder permission.I think CI used GD extension as well.Check the extension enabled or not.

Comment: Is your `base_url()` set correctly on your online site? Have a look at the source (not dev tools) and see what (if anything) is being echo'd

Comment: Yes as @Samy says check the GD extension is enabled in your php config

Comment: i dont know if this is a good question, but, how do you check GD extension is enabled or not

Comment: I have checked my server details, and yes GD is enabled, and there is png file extension support also, still not working, it must be the codeigniter script, help me guys...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the script had some issues, it needed extra parameters, the code which is working is:

```
$vals = array(

    'img_path' => './captcha/',
    'img_url' => 'http://example.com/captcha/',
    'font_path' => './fonts/texb.ttf',
    'img_width' => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 7200
    );

$cap = create_captcha($vals);
$data = $cap['image'];
$this->load->view(signup, $data);
```

and in the view file

```
echo $image;
```

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer

Answer (score 0):

From the [captcha helper page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html)

> The "captcha" folder must be writable (666, or 777)
>
> The captcha function requires the GD image library.

Make sure these are true on your online site.

Comment: Setting these things is very circumstantial based on which hosting provider you use and which tools you use for uploading and interacting with files. I would suggest you have a search on google for these things and/or contact your hosting provider for support

Comment: phpinfo(); use this function in any of your page and see the output. Check for GD

Comment: I have checked my server details, and yes GD is enabled, and there is png file extension support also, still not working, it must be the codeigniter script, help me guys...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the htaccess file to include the captcha folder like

```
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|captcha|inc|images|robots\.txt)
```

had the same issue but it worked for me. Remember to first create a backup of the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

For me, enough to add the name of the directory "captcha" to rule in the file .htaccess. Like wrote as poly :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|captcha|inc|images|robots\.txt)
```